# Ubuntu 16.04 Bluetooth issues-Headset will connect but stops all playback of audio

Tags: sound, 16.04, bluetooth, disconnect

I am using a set of Plantronics BBGO2's. They worked on 14.04 but they arent working on 16.04. I go into the bluetooth menu and find my headset, click to sync up but disconnects as soon as i exit the setup screen. Turning on and off the connection does nothing. When I finally get headset to pair the bluetooth icon gets the padlock, I go into the sound settings and move input and output to my headset and close the sound control it automatically reverts back to my computer speakers. I open up the sound control again, set the input and output back to my headset and leave it open and youtube videos, rythmbox, and even rhapsody all refuse to play.. not even system sounds work. I am not sure what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar problem with a set of speakers with a 'headset' function.

I found that if I changed the Mode: from 'High fidelity playback' to 'Headset head unit' in sound settings under output I got sound (although poor quality). I then disconnected and reconnected and could switch back to high fidelity without any trouble.

Comment: I do not have the ability to even select high fidelity playback :/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and took a clue from the previous answer. In the Sound settings, find "Profile." There you will (hopefully) see an option for "High Fidelity Playback."

Choose that and see if it fixes your problem. It did for me.